# Where is the line drawn on seeding?

Tags: discussion

I'm a big advocate of self-answered questions when the answer has genuine value. As I'm guilty of doing this myself on [one occasion](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store) on here.

I know seeding a BETA is considered bad form - so I just wanted to know what we should do when someone deliberately [asks a simple question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/515/what-are-the-definitions-of-the-order-statuses-or-where-should-i-integrate-my) and posts a simple answer just to get points.

Is it just a case of down voting + comment, or moderator report?

Comment: "seeding a BETA is considered bad form" - source?

Comment: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/a/21/361